# Execute "complex" command in .desktop file (Unity Quicklist)

Tags: unity, launcher

I'm trying to create an Twitter quicklist desktop file, but I can figured how to resolve one thing.

To compose an message at Twitter, I made the following command:
Exec=xdg-open 'https://twitter.com/#!/' && sleep 3 && xdotool key n

(execute)+(open browser)+(Twitter main URL)+ Some seconds to open + Keyboard shorcut to compose.

If I use in terminal, works fine. But in the .desktop file (to make Unity Quicklist) it just doesn't work. Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would use

```
Exec=sh -c "xdg-open 'https://twitter.com/#!/' && sleep 3 && xdotool key n"
```

Comment: Work just perfect. Can you just explain what sh em -c mean? (I'm not an advanced Linux programer, hehe)

Comment: @euDennis: you are using &&, that is a shell construct, so you have to use a shell, i.e. sh, or also bash